# Initiating an enum as value

Tags: java, enums

I want to declare an enum variable as values. How can I achieve that?

For Example:

```
public enum CardSuit {
   SPADE(0), HEART(1), DIAMOND(2), CLUB(3);
}
```

I can declare like this:

```
CardSuit s = CardSuit.SPADE;
```

I want to declare like this too:

```
CardSuit s = 1;
```

What is the way of doing that? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel, Thanks for the editing. As this is my first post, I kinda messed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
public static enum CardSuit {
    SPADE(0), HEART(1), DIAMOND(2), CLUB(3);
    int value;

    CardSuit(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardSuit s = CardSuit.values()[0];
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output is

```
SPADE
```

**Edit**

If you wanted to search by the assigned value, you could do it with something like this -

```
public static enum CardSuit {
    SPADE(0), HEART(1), DIAMOND(4), CLUB(2);
    int value;

    CardSuit(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name();
    }

    public static CardSuit byValue(int value) {
        for (CardSuit cs : CardSuit.values()) {
            if (cs.value == value) {
                return cs;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardSuit s = CardSuit.byValue(2);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output is

```
CLUB
```

Comment: How about maintaining a map instead of traversing the whole values every time, It wont cause a big impact on performance but still?

Comment: Many many thanks. It worked. Though I tried to figure out finally with switch..case. Yours one better.

Comment: @Karna [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). - Knuth.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Nice link. Looks like I am over thinking about optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a factory method:

```
public enum CardSuit {
    SPADE(0), HEART(1), DIAMOND(2), CLUB(3);

    private final int value;
    CardSuit(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public static CardSuit of(int value) {
        for (CardSuit cs : values()) {
            if (cs.value == value) return cs;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid value: " + value);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardSuit s = CardSuit.of(0);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: How about maintaining a map instead of traversing the whole values every time, It wont cause a big impact on performance but still?

Comment: @Karna for a larger number of enum constants it would make sense, but in this case ***a map may actually be slower*** as you will have to box the int to Integer, get the hashcode, rehash, calculate a modulus and then access an array vs. a maximum of 4 comparisons and an array access if you use a plain for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a map with value and corresponding Enum

```
public enum CardSuit {
    SPADE(0), HEART(1), DIAMOND(2), CLUB(3);

    private CardSuit(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private int value;

    private static Map<Integer, CardSuit> getByValue = new HashMap<Integer, CardSuit>();

    public static CardSuit findByValue(int value) {
        if (getByValue.isEmpty()) {
            for (CardSuit cardSuit : CardSuit.values()) {
                getByValue.put(cardSuit.getValue(), cardSuit);
            }
        }
        return getByValue.get(value);
    }

}
```

and you can do

```
CardSuit s = CardSuit.findByValue(1);
```

Comment: Static function must be needed. Updated one works well.

Comment: I like the idea of using the map.  In previous versions of this sort of Enum, I would have iterated through the Enum values directly.  Pretty sure the performance difference would be minimal.

Comment: Is there not a synchronization issue should multiple threads call findByValue in quick succession?

Comment: @sfosdal yup. Also the `Map` is a little wasted with 4 values - see the comments on [assylias's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23496309/2071828).